# Problema al invertir palabras separadas por comas

Tags: c, web, programación-móvil, error404

Me gustaría que a partir de una entrada de texto ("hola,mundo") revierta cada palabra, sin embargo, revierte todo el texto.

La salida debería ser algo como: ("aloh,odnum")

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char palabra[1000];
    int i, tam
    printf("Introduce las palabras separadas por comas: ");
    fgets(palabra,1000,stdin);
    // En la entrada es: hola,saludos,como,estan
    tam = strlen(palabra);
    for(i=tam; i>=0; i--){
        printf("%c", palabra[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Pero en la salida en vez de ser: "aloh,sodulas,omoc,natse" en mi programa sale: "natse,omoc,sodulas,aloh" ¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Answer (score 1):

No hay ningún problema en tu código.

La razón por la que ves el texto al revés es porque estás recorriendo el arreglo al revés.

Lo que puedes hacer es ubicar el código de imprimir las palabras al revés en una función a la que se le indique un inicio y un fin. Para recorrer de forma normal el arreglo encontrando las posiciones de los delimitadores.

```
void voltear(char* str, int inicio, int fin){
     for(int i = fin; i >= inicio; i--){
          printf("%c", str[i]);
     } 
}
```

En el main:

```
int inicio = 0;
char delimitador = ',';
for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++){
    if(palabra[i] == delimitador){
          int fin = i - 1;
          voltear(palabra, inicio, fin);
          printf(", ");
          inicio = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: O no lo he entendido bien o me parece que esto no responde a la pregunta ¿dónde se separa la cadena de entrada por las comas y se "da la vuelta" a cada una de las palabras resultantes?

Answer (score 1):

Primero se necesita separar las palabras (están separadas por una coma) para, luego, revertir las letras de cada palabra.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>  
#include <vector>  
#include <sstream>  


int main()
{
    string S, T;  // declarar variables  string
    printf("Introduce las palabras separadas por comas: ");

    getline(cin, S); // usar la función getline() para leer una línea y almacenarla en S.  

    stringstream X(S); // X es un objeto stringstream que referencia al string S

    bool b = (bool) getline(X, T, ',');
    /* X representa leer el string de stringstream, T para almacenar 
      el token string (esto es, una palabra) y,
     ',' la coma representa extraer la cadena o string cuando se alcance una coma. */
    // usar un loop while loop para comprobar la condición de getline()
    while (b) {

        for (int i = T.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // revertir las letras de la palabra
            printf("%c", T[i]);
        }
        b = (bool) getline(X, T, ',');
        if (b)
            printf("%c", ','); // si no es la última palabra, separar con una coma
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Solución c++ en un programa en c????

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `strtok` para separar la cadena original por comas. El siguiente paso sería recorrer cada subcadena e invertirla.

```
char original[] = "hola,mundo,cruel";
char final[100];

char * ptr = final; // Para ir escribiendo la secuencia final

char* subcadena = strtok(original, ",");
while (subcadena != NULL)
{
    if (ptr != final)
    {
        *ptr = ',';
        ++ptr;
    }

    int len = strlen(subcadena);
    for( int i=len-1; i>=0; --i, ++ptr)
    {
       *ptr = subcadena[i];
    }

    subcadena = strtok(NULL, ",");
}

*ptr = '\0'; // Finalizamos la cadena final

puts(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma es primero buscar `,` o `\n`, luego te devuelves imprimiendo en reversa y al terminar la palabra en reversa sigues donde dejaste para buscar la siguiente palabra.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char palabra[1000];
    char temp[1000];
    int cont = 0, prev = 0;
    printf("Introduce las palabras separadas por comas: ");
    fgets(palabra, 1000, stdin);
    // En la entrada es: hola,saludos,como,estan

    while (1)
    {
        temp[cont] = palabra[cont];
        if (palabra[cont] == ',' || palabra[cont] == '\n')
        {
            for (int i = cont - 1; i >= prev; i--)
            {
                printf("%c", temp[i]);
            }
            prev = cont+1;
            if (palabra[cont] == '\n')
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (palabra[cont] == ',')
            {
                printf(",");
            }
        }
        cont++;
    }

    printf("%c", palabra[cont]);

    return 0;
}
```